# FileDialog filters doesn't work

Tags: macos, qt

I use a few file dialog in my Qt Application and I notice a strange behavior : when I try to change the filters the incorrect types are deactivated only if I resize the window (you can see an example [here on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ty36-OSG21g))

It only happen on `Mac Os 10.9.x.`

As the issue is also present in Firefox, I assume that it's not coming from me. Anyone has an idea of how to fix that ?

Comment: Report a bug to Apple, and keep your fingers crossed that they fix it :)

Comment: @KubaOber done, I'm also writing a letter to Santa Claus to see which will answer first !

Answer (score 1):

Since this also happens on Firefox which does not use Qt, it is probably a bug of Mac OS, so you cannot really address the bug. What you can try is to connect the `filterSelected` signal of your dialog to a method which either calls

```
dialog.repaint();
```

or

```
dialog.resize (dialog.size());
```

or, if all of the above fail,

```
QSize size = dialog.size();
dialog.resize (size.width() + 1, size.height());
dialog.resize (size);
```

and hope that one of these workarounds will trigger the necessary events.

Comment: I used this `connect(&dlg, SIGNAL(filterSelected(QString)), &dlg, SLOT(repaint()));` `dlg` being the dialog which cause the issue and it doesn't work...

Comment: And the other two options?